# how to enter < br > from database

Tags: html, fullcalendar

I'm entering text in my html from a database.  Usually when I enter `<br>` it works fine but for some reason I'm getting  `lt;brgt;` when I try to do this in a section using `fullcalendar`.  I also tried \n but that didn't work either.  Is there a way to add the `< br >` to the database to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On version 5.5.1 you can use this

```
eventContent: function(eventInfo) {
       return { html: eventInfo.event.title }
}
```

if your title has a 
 that will be taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

Databases usually (not sure which DB you are using) do not automatically convert or escape special characters.

So I guess somewhere in your code you are encoding the special characters before inserting them into the DB. So now you have to decode those after retrieving them from the DB.

If you are using Java then you can use `StringEscapeUtils`'s `escapeHtml4` `unescapeHtml4` functions to encode and decode.

If you are using PHP then you can use `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlspecialchars_decode` to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

For fullcalendar, you will have to use the `eventRender` to do so. Try this hack

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    element.find('.fc-title').html(event.title);
}
```

Comment: Please see code updated in your answer.  Thanks for your help

Comment: ahh eventRender is giving me unknown option

Comment: I'm using version 5.  I tried eventContent and eventDidMount but can't get your function to work.  Do you have a suggestion for version 5?

Comment: uh. don't update my answer, update your question. :)

Comment: sorry about that.  Can you help with version 5?